# Sort text file by first column and count repeats python

Tags: python, sorting, count

I have a text file that needs to be sorted by the first column and merge all repeats with the count to the left of the data, and then write the sorted/counted data into an already created csv file.

Ex text file:

```
, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 00.000.00.001, word, 00
, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
```

Ex result:

```
, 3, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 1, 00.000.00.001, word, 00
, 2, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
```

My code:

```
for ip in open("list.txt"):
    with open(ip.strip()+".txt", "a") as ip_file:
        for line in open("data.txt"):
            new_line = line.split(" ")
            if "blocked" in new_line:
                if "src="+ip.strip() in new_line:
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[11])
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[13])

for ip_file in os.listdir(sub_dir):
        with open(os.path.join(sub_dir, ip_file), "a") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            data.sort(key = lambda l: float(l.split()[0]), reverse = True)
```

Whenever I test the code, I get the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` or something similar. I can't use `.split() .read() .strip()` etc without getting the error.

**Question**: How can I sort the files' contents and count repeating lines (without defining a function)?

I'm basically trying to:

```
sort -k1 | uniq -c | sed 's/^/,/' >> test.csv
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?  I see no point where the code could try to call a `str`.

Comment: For counting repetitions you could use `collections.Counter` or `itertools.groupby()`.

Comment: @Alfe: I don't either but it occurs at: `data = file(f).readlines()`

Comment: Did you assign `file` to a string elsewhere in the code? That would explain the error. You shouldn't be using `file` anyway, just `f.readlines()`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: `file` was a mistake, but I edited my code. `filename` = `ip_file` and `f` should be what was written to `ip_file` in the previous block of code.

Comment: So where do you get the error? What line?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: at line 3 in `data = f.readlines()`

Comment: `repr(f)` shows you what?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: `"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='1308231017-src\\\\108.28.193.114.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>"` and after changing some code, I now get the error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`

Comment: from what I can tell, that's not a valid file name; which would explain the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D = {}
for k in open('data.txt'): #use dictionary to count and filter duplicate lines
    if k in D:
        D[k] += 1 #increase k by one if already seen.
    else:
        D[k]  = 1 #initialize key with one if seen for first time.

for sk in sorted(D): #sort keys 
    print(',', D[sk], sk.rstrip(), file=open('test.csv', 'a')) #print a comma, followed by number of lines plus line.   

#Output
, 3, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 1, 00.000.00.001, word, 00
, 2, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. How would I convert `print` to `csv_file.write` as write only allows one argument?

Comment: I edited the print function argument to redirect the output to a file in append mode. Please let me know if that will do it for you.

Comment: That worked so perfectly. I have been working on this problem for way too long. Thanks so very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
input = ''', 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 00.000.00.001, word, 00
, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
, 00.000.00.000, word, 00
, 00.000.00.002, word, 00
, 00.000.00.000, word, 00'''.split('\n')

input.sort(key=lambda line: line.split(',')[1])

for key, values in itertools.groupby(input, lambda line: line.split(',')[1]):
  values = list(values)
  print ', %d%s' % (len(values), values[0])
```

This lacks all error checking (like unfit lines etc.), but maybe you can add that yourself according to your needs.  Also, the `split` is performed twice; once for the sorting and once for the grouping.  That probably can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the Pandas Data Processing Module

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv("C:\Where My Data Lives\Data.txt", header=None)
sorted_data = my_data.sort_index(by=[1], ascending=1)  # sort my data
sorted_data = sorted_data.drop_duplicates([1])         # leaves only unique values, sorted in order
counted_data = list(my_data.groupby(1).size())         #counts the unique values in data, coverts to a list
sorted_data[0] = counted_data                          # inserts the list into your data frame
```

Comment: The only problem with using pandas is that installation of the package is required, and everything must be done from the py script, with no work required from the user

Comment: @hjames, I am not sure I follow your statement. Are you looking for a base Python solution (no extra modules)? This script will not require the user to do anything besides type and run the code :)

Comment: Hm, I just assumed that I would need to install the pandas package in order to import the module?