# How to sort a csv file through python script?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have read other answers to similar questions on google and on this site, and none of them work in my script.

I need to sort information in a `csv_file` by the third column from a py script. And then, with the sorted info, find duplicates and remove them but add a count to the csv_file.

```
for ip in open("lists.txt"):
    with open("csv_file.csv", "a") as csv_file:
        csv_file.write("\r IP:" + ip.strip() + ", Count, A, B, C \r")
        for line in open("data.txt"):
            new_line = line.split()
            if "word" in new_line:
                if "word"+ip.strip() in new_line:
                    csv_file.write(ip.strip() + ", " + new_line[10].replace("word=", ", ") + new_line[12].replace("word=", ", "))
                    try:
                        csv_file.write(new_line[14].replace("word=", ", "))
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
                    csv_file.write("\r")
with open("csv_file.csv", "r") as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        key = (row[0], row[1:])
        if key not in rows:
            rows[key] = row + [0,]
        rows[key][-1] += 1
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, and returning errors like:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Question**: How do I sort by the 3rd column, remove duplicates and add a duplicate count to my csv_file through a py script?

Comment: you mean `reader.next()`, not `next(reader)`

Comment: How big is the csv file?

Comment: @yosukesabai: Why `reader.next()`? @bill: 266KB

Comment: sorry I have to take that back.... next() should be fine.  opening 'a' may be the problem as the answer by Benjamin says.

Comment: Didn't you just [ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404501/sort-text-file-by-first-column-and-count-repeats-python#comment27035381_18404501)? How is this different than the previous one?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: for this script, I'd like to use the csv module and also, there are no dictionaries/extra files in this script. I write everything directly to the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the "a" tag opens for writing in this line:

```
with open("csv_file.csv", "a") as inputfile:
```

This means you're opening for writing, not for reading. You should use either "r" or "+".